# Accessing a javascript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

After creating an object with JavaScript I am looking to access it with jQuery to manipulate it. Here is some code to make things clearer:

```
ObjectFunction = function(content) {
  this.content = content
}

ObjectFunction.prototype = {
   showobject : { return this.appendTo(document.body)}
}

obj = New ObjectFunction()
```

What I would like to do is as follows, but the syntax is wrong:

```
$(obj).css{(background:'red')}
```

This doesn't work. If I create a function in prototype, which would look something like this, it works:

```
ObjectFunction.prototype = {
 showobject :  { return this.appendTo(document.body)},
 objectmodify: { return this.css{(background:'red')}}
}

// then call something like 
obj.objectmodify()
```

Is there any way to avoid this ugly code for a direct jQuery function applied on the object?

Comment: please format your code as such, it's more readable that way.

Comment: Capital N for New should not work. On what browser did it work for you?

Comment: Also, in what browser did calling `return` outside of function scope works?

Comment: Please provide the most correct working copy you have. It's hard to guess which part of the code is really wrong if there are deliberate or accidental copy/paste errors in it.

Answer (score 1):

> $(obj).css{(background:'red')}

The syntax of this is wrong, you have the parenthesis and squigly's the wrong way round - it should be

`$(obj).css({background:'red'});`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. as always it was simpler than i thought.

the dom element created is referenced as a property of the javascript object. which can be accessed in this case ( see the code above ) by obj.content so in the is case $(obj.content).css({background:'red'}). works :) I hope this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write:

```
$(obj).css("background","red");
```

or

```
$(obj).attr('style', 'background:red');
```

Comment: That does not make sense in javascript. Should be: `$(obj).css({'background':'red'})`. jQuery is a javascript library, the language is STILL javascript.

Comment: @slebetman - that broken syntax is in the original question - looks like an inadvertent copy-paste to me.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work. 
if i run $(obj).size() the result is 1 but somehow i dont see the effect on the object

Comment: the code is not an exact copy of what i have so the capital letters and other obvious mistakes can be ignored. the code works fine except for the jquery call to the object .

Comment: Yeah, this question is borken somehow (note the bork). Applying DOM manipulations, which is what jQuery essentially wraps, to a non-DOM object doesn't make a shred of sense. I suspect there is a deeper question about the understanding of javascript that the OP should really be asking. Perhaps the function should return a DOM object but the OP doesn't know how to do it?

Comment: the object constuctor does create a dom object  perhaps there is a way to connect the two but i assumed that if an object has a method that creates a dom object this dom object is linked to the javascript object. It sounds like this isnt the case. How would I go about doing that then?
thanks :)

Comment: I figured out the answer. as always it was simpler than i thought
the dom element created is referenced as a property of the javascript object. which can be accessed in this case ( see the code above ) by  obj.content
so in the is case $(obj.content).css({background:'red'}). works :)
I hope this helps someone out there :)